# Calculation of cutoff frequency in larger circuit

Tags: capacitor, resistors, frequency

I'm having some difficulties choosing appropriate resistors and capacitors to get specific cutoff frequencies. I guess it's because I'm just considering the single pole components rather then the whole circuit when I'm dimensioning my filter. Given this circuit:

[image]

What should I consider when choosing values for the resistors and capacitors to get a 2MHz cutoff bandpass filter and at the same time a DC component of 1.65V?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "2 MHz cutoff bandpass filter". If you want a bandpass filter centered at 2 MHz, what is the bandwidth you want around that?

Comment: What I mean is I want frequencies above and below 2MHz to get suppressed.

Comment: How far above and how far below 2 MHz before they get supressed? Should 1.99 MHz be supressed? By how much? Should 1.8 MHz be suprressed? You have defined a center frequency for your bandpass filter, but you haven't defined the bandwidth. If you design this with discrete components (as opposed to a crystal resonator or somethign) you will also need to decide what's the maximum attenuation in the pass band, how wide a transition band you can have, and what's the minimum attenuation in the stop band.

Comment: If you just want to play around with values, this might help: http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/RLCbpkeisan.htm

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link but isn't that for circuits where the only components included are the ones specific for the circuit. The thing is, I'm having problems knowing what parts of the signal that contributes to the filtering. For example, how does R5 contribute to the filtering?

Comment: you can use the tool that I linked to get the R/L/C values. Then plug them in to any SPICE simulator you like to see how the circuit is affected by source and load impedance or whatever.

Comment: As for R5, as far as ac signals are concerned, it's in parallel with R6, so just imagine the filter is formed by C6, R5||R6, R17, and C5.

Answer (score 1):

LT1818 is a poor choice to run from a single 3.3V supply - you need something that is specified to run from a 3.3V supply with rail-to-rail inputs and outputs. AD8031 springs to mind.

Regarding the filtering the low frequency cut-off is determined by C6 and R6 in parallel with R5. HF cut off filtering is determined by C5 and R17.

Because it is both a HP and LP filter you'll need to spread the HP lower than 2MHz and the LP higher than 2MHz to get any decent flatness and easily predictable gain at 2MHz. Typically if HP=LP=2MHz a signal at 2MHz would be "down" by 6dB.

Comment: Second paragraph is not helpful. Obviously, the OP is not getting anywhere with this oversimplified approach. He'll need to consider all six components when determining the cutoff frequencies of the filter.

Comment: Which six components do you mean?

Comment: @DaveTweed is referring to the fact that there are several components contributing to the overall frequency response and there is some inter-dependancy between those components performing low-pass operations and those performing high-pass. I suspect the components he refers to are R20, C6, R6, R5, R17 and C5. Do you understand the answers so far and the implications of what Dave and I are saying?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, understand that there is some interdependencies. But how can I calculate the frequencies? Btw, can I neglect the op-amp part of the circuit because it has a very high internal resistance?